# Some images are automatically rotated when i picked with image picker in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

I use image_picker: ^0.8.4 in my flutter app.When i wan't to pick image from gallery some images are automatically rotated .How can i solve this problem?

I try image_picker: ^0.8.5+3 and image_picker: ^0.8.6 packages.I want to pick image as it show in gallery without any rotation And i also want to keep meta data.

**This is my code :**

```
Future<XFile?> _getImage(ImageSource source, ImagePicker _picker) async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: source,imageQuality: 25);
    return pickedFile;
  }
```

Comment: Android or iOS or both?

Comment: Hello, maybe this issue on github can help you: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35334

Comment: if your problem exists after reading that link please let us know to help you.

Comment: @GrahamD I'm facing in both.